Symmetry in octic polynomial's root
I am working on a problem of shell theory (for computational mechanics) and I am trying to find the roots of the octic:
$$
p(m) = m^8 + a m^6 + b m^5 + c m^4 + d m^3 + e m^2 + f m + g = 0
$$
Where $a,c,e,g \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b,d,f \in \mathbb{Z}$. All the coefficients are functions of other 5 parameters which I don't know a priori. All these parameters are real.
Edit: The expressions of the coefficients are:
$$ a = - \left(4 \alpha^2 + \kappa \lambda^4_2\right) $$
$$ b = - (4 \kappa \lambda_{12}^2 \lambda_2^2 \alpha) i$$
$$ c = \left(6 \alpha^4 + \lambda_2^4 + \kappa \alpha^2 \left(\lambda^4_2 + 4 \lambda_{12}^4 + 2 \lambda_1^2 \lambda_{2}^2 \right) \right) $$
$$ d = - 4 \alpha \lambda_{12}^2 \left( \lambda_2^2 + \kappa \alpha^2 \left( \lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2 \right)\right)i$$
$$ e = - \alpha^2 \left(4 \alpha^4 + 2 \left( 2 \lambda_{12}^4 + \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2^2\right) + \kappa \alpha^2 \left( \lambda_1^4 + 4 \lambda_{12}^4 + 2 \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2^2 \right)\right) $$
$$ f = - 4 \alpha^3 \lambda_1^2 \lambda_{12}^2 \left(\kappa \alpha^2 + 1 \right) i $$
$$ g = \alpha^4 \left(\alpha^4 + \lambda_1^4 \left(1 + \kappa \alpha^2\right)\right) $$
Where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_{12} \in [0,10]$, $\kappa \in [0.001,0.1]$ and $\alpha \in [0, + \infty]$.
I can solve this equation numerically by Newton-Rapson method for small $\alpha$, but for larger values (i.e., $\alpha > 15$) the coefficients become to large and the solution becomes unstable. It seems that the solutions converge to two families of roots, meaning that four roots have modulus $m_1$ and phases $\gamma, -\gamma, \pi - \gamma, \pi + \gamma$ and four have modulus $m_2$ and phases $\theta, -\theta, \pi - \theta, \pi + \theta$ with $m_1 < m_2$ and $\gamma < \theta$.
2nd edit: The polynomial is the characteristic equation which is obtained by using the Fourier transform:
$$ w(x,y) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,\alpha) e^{-i \alpha y} d \alpha $$
And assuming:
$$ f(x, \alpha) = R(\alpha) e^{mx} $$
To solve the equation:
$$ \nabla^8 w + \left(1 - \kappa \nabla^2\right) \left(\lambda_1^4 \partial_{yyyy}+ \lambda_2^4 \partial_{xxxx} - 4 \lambda_{12}^2 \left( \lambda_1^2\partial_{xyyy} + \lambda_2^2 \partial_{xxxy}\right) + \left( 4 \lambda_{12}^4 + 2 \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2^2 \right) \partial_{xxyy}\right) w = 0 $$
This is the out-of-plane equilibrium equation of the shell. The polynomial is obtained by substituting $f$ into the transform of $w$, substituting the transform into the equation and then taking the exponent of the exponential term.
3rd edit: the source paper mention that one can "retain four constants for each half of the shell", meaning four for $x>0$ and four for $x<0$. This is motivated by noticing that for a substitution $m \to i s$, $p(s)$ has real coefficients and thus $Im(s_j) = - Im(s_{j+4})$ with $j = 1,...4$. This leads to $Re(m_j) = - Re(m_{j+4})$ with $Re(m_j) <0$, so that the function $f(x,\alpha)$ can be rewritten as:
$$ f(x, \alpha) =  \begin{cases} \sum_{j =1}^4 R_j(\alpha) e^{m_jx} & x > 0 \\ \sum_{j =5}^8 R_j(\alpha) e^{m_jx} & x < 0 \end{cases} $$
I am planning to substitute the second form of $f$ into the polynomial and see if this simplifies the problem.

From the moment a polynome has a degree of five or more, a simple form of the solution can't exist (for the general case).

The title mentions symmetry, but there is no symmetry in the problem expression.

I am aware of order 5 being the upper bound for a general solution of a polynomial. I edited the polynomial with the actual expression of the coefficients.

(i) So all odd powers of $m$ have imaginary coefficients? If so, then replacing $m\to im$ in the polynomial will make it have all  real coefficients.  (ii) I see five parameters, not four.  Why do some of them belong to  ${\mathbb Z}?$ (iii). Suggest retaining only highest powers of $\alpha$ in each coefficient as a crude initial simplification.

Then ry using this idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series

Some details are here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.4674

Part 1. Reformatting the original differential equation
After reading the articles you posted in comments I believe that your ultimate goal  is to  solve
$ \nabla^8 w + \left(1 - \kappa \nabla^2\right) \left(\lambda_1^4 \partial_{yyyy}+ \lambda_2^4 \partial_{xxxx} - 4 \lambda_{12}^2 \left( \lambda_1^2\partial_{xyyy} + \lambda_2^2 \partial_{xxxy}\right) + \left( 4 \lambda_{12}^4 + 2 \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2^2 \right) \partial_{xxyy}\right) w = 0 $
This can be  written more compactly and more informatively by noting that the rightmost fourth-order differential operator
$$\left(\lambda_1^4 \partial_{yyyy}+ \lambda_2^4 \partial_{xxxx} - 4 \lambda_{12}^2 \left( \lambda_1^2\partial_{xyyy} + \lambda_2^2 \partial_{xxxy}\right) + \left( 4 \lambda_{12}^4 + 2 \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2^2 \right) \partial_{xxyy}\right)$$
can be factored as $D^2$ (the square of a second-order operator $D$)
where $$D= \lambda_{1}^2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial ^2y} - 2 \lambda^2_{1,2} \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \partial y} + \lambda_2^2 \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}$$
Note incidentally that depending  on the sign of the discriminant $ \Delta= \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2^2 - \lambda_{1,2}^4$, the second-order operator $D$ can be either elliptic(+), parabolic (0), or hyperbolic (-). (In the latter case it  is essentially the 2D wave equation expressed in a set of oblique coordinates.)
Anyway, your differential equation takes the form
$$(1) \qquad \nabla^8 w + \left(1 - \kappa \nabla^2\right)D^2 w=0$$
Part 2. Seeking pure plane-wave exponential solutions
Your goal is to use Fourier analysis to express $w$ as a superposition of special elementary solutions of the exponential form
(2) $w= e^{my} e^{-i ax} =e^{isy} e^{-i ax}$ where $m=is$
These are of course eigenfunctions under the action of the constant-coefficient differential operators $\nabla^2$  and  $D$.
In particular the following identities  are satisfied by the exponential function $w$ defined by (2):
(3) $\nabla ^2 w= -(s^2+a^2) w\implies \nabla^8 w= (s^2+a^2)^4 w$
(4) $Dw= -(\lambda_1^2 s^2 -2  \lambda^2_{1,2}s a + \lambda_2^2 a^2)w=- Q(s,a) w$ where $Q(s,a)=\lambda_1^2 s^2 -2  \lambda^2_{1,2}s a + \lambda_2^2 a^2$ is a quadratic form in $(s,a)$
Part 3. A variant of polar coordinates for the $(s,a)$ frequency plane
It is convenient to adopt " hyperbolic polar coordinates" in the $(s,a)$ frequency plane by setting
Hyperbolic polars: $$ a= r \cosh t, m=r\sinh t $$  Thus $s= -im=-ir \sinh t$
(Ultimately we will see that for our purposes $t$ can be assumed real, but in general  $r$ may be complex.
Then $s^2+ a^2= r^2 (\cosh^2 t-\sinh^2 t) = r^2 $.
Thus  we seek solutions
of $$(5)\qquad r^8 + (1+ \kappa  r^2 ) Q^2(-ir\sinh t , r\cosh t)=0$$
But we can factor out $r^2$ from the quadratic $Q$ to deduce $Q(-ir\sinh t , r\cosh t) =r^2 Q(-i\sinh t , \cosh t)$. Thus the square of $Q$ is
$Q^2(-ir\sinh t , r\cosh t) =r^4 Q^2(-i\sinh t , \cosh t)$. Thus
(1) becomes
$$(6)\qquad  r^8  +(1+\kappa r^2 )r^4  Q^2(-i\sinh t, \cosh t)=0$$
Thus after cancelling $r^4$ we deduce that $r^2=\rho $ satisfies the quadratic  equation
$$ \rho^2  +(1+\kappa \rho )Q^2(-i\sinh t, \cosh t)=0$$
Thus after solving the quadratic, the two values of $\rho$ can be written as  explicit complex-valued expressions in hyperbolic functions of $t$.
Summarizing, for each $t$ one can solve for two values of the complex-valued quantity $\rho$, each of which in turn then generates two values for $r$; then use  the hyperbolic polar coordinate equations  to determine four distinct complex pure-wave functions $w= e^{my - iax}$.
Part 4 . Asymptotic behavior for large r.
Try setting $u=1/\rho$ and solving
$$   1+(u^2+\kappa u )Q^2(-i\sinh t, \cosh t)=0$$  for $u$  as a function of $t$, noting $u^2<< u$ and thus
$$  1\approx -(\kappa u )Q^2(-i\sinh t, \cosh t)$$
Thus $$ u^{-1}=\rho^2 =r^4 \approx -{\kappa )Q^2(-i\sinh t, \cosh t)}$$
For each choice of $t$, the four complex values of $r$ that satisfy this equation can be inserted into the polar coordinate equations to determine four values of $a$ and $m$.
Note also that by replacing $t\to -t$ you obtain a complementary set of four other solutions that reverse the sign  of $m$.
Special Cases. In the special case that $\lambda_{1,2}=0$ the expression $Q(-i\sinh t, \cosh t) $  turns out to be a purely real combination of squares of hyperbolic functions. In your comments you mentioned that this special case has a relatively simpler solution, so you have an opportunity to check that the preceding analysis agrees with that known solution.
Part 5.  Other approaches
I see another approach to the more general forced equation that appears in your first citation:
$$ (7)\qquad \nabla^8 w + \left(1 - \kappa \nabla^2\right)D^2 w=q$$
One can use advanced complex-variable methods to express this equation in a modern symbolic format that exploits the algebraic properties of analytic functions and their complex conjugates.
One can use Wirtinger notation Wirtinger derivativesto express $\nabla ^2= 4\partial_z \partial_{\overline z} $. Here $\partial_{\overline z}= \frac{1}{2} (\partial_x + i \partial_y)$ and similarly for the conjugate operator: $\partial_{ z}= \frac{1}{2} (\partial_x - i \partial_y)$.
Note that you can invert these two relations to express $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ in terms of the two Wirtinger operators. Then one can express $D$ as a linear combination of various two-fold products of these two Wirtinger operators: the real second-order operator $D= A \partial_z^2 + \overline A \partial_{\overline z}^2 + B \partial_z \partial_{\overline z}$.
The advantage of such notation is that e.g. Laurent series in inverse powers of $z$ and $\overline z$  of the form  $$f(z, \overline z)=\sum_{j,k} c_{j,k} \frac{1}{z^{j}} \frac{1}{ (\overline z)^{k}}$$ can quickly be  differentiated  termwise  using the "obvious" product and power rules satisfied by $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\overline z}$.
This should allow you to construct explicit examples of solutions to the forced equation by matching the corresponding terms in the Laurent expansions of $w$ and the forcing term $q$.
Another advantage of this approach is that these operators transform relatively simply when you  perform a conformal transformation of the $z$ plane.  Such transformations allow you to alter the shape and location of slits in the $z$ plane, should you wish to model materials that have stationary cracks.
Finally, given a straight or curvilinear slit $S$, one can seek conjectured solutions of (7)  of the form  $ w(z,\overline z)= \int _{t\in S} \frac{A(t) dt}{z-t} +\int_{t\in S}\frac{ B(t) dt}{\overline z - t}+ \int_{t\in S} \frac{C(t)}{z\overline z -t}$ which can be inserted into (7) and expanded in Laurent series as above. By making special choices of $A(t),B(t),C(t)$ one can deduce relations between the solution $w$and its forcing term $q$. This approach could allow you to directly model the discontinuities of the solution on opposite sides of the slit $S$.

Thank you so much! It turns out that the solutions of $P_0(x) = 0$ are not distinct (one gets $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = - i $ and $x_5 = x_6 = x_7 = x_8 = i $.
I will look into the Puiseux expansions. I am not a mathematician, this I am not sure I understand the post scriptum :(

I am trying to use a Puiseux series but it seems that by constructing the Newton's polygon of $P(x,a) = 0$ with $x$ on the horizontal and $a$ on the vertical axis one gets 4 points on the x-axis. \Thus, $\gamma_1 = 0$ (the negative of the slope of lowest segment of the polygon, from the previous paper) and the algorithm cannot progress. Am I missing something?

My guess is that your polynomial arose as the characteristic polynomial of some linear system. If so, perhaps you could add more detailed info about the structure of that original system to your posting. There might be a way to exploit that additional info.

See updated posting for a solution to a stripped-down version of your problem.

It is a characteristic polynomial, but not from a linear system. I added a short description with the 2nd edit

@DesperateGrad See fresh update 2 for a new approach

Hi, thanks again. The eigenvalues approach might work, but I want to obtain the roots $m_j$ to be able to derive some quantities later in the analysis.
After some more time spent on the source paper and working on the problem, I am starting to think again that I am missing some symmetry in the roots. I will add a third update to the question

I suggest you try declutter $Q$ by making the change of scale $x->x/\lambda_1$ and $y-> y/lambda_2$ so that now $Q$ appears to depend on fewer parameters.

I need to stress that I interested in the roots of the polynomial, not really in the displacement field $\omega$ for the time being. The steps you suggest might work but are drifting away from the the scope of this question.

I have been doing further research and it appears that a similar problem has been solved for the case $\lambda_{12} = 0$ with the substitution $m^2 = \rho + \alpha^2$. I am aware that such case is a much simpler case, but this is convincing  me that with some sort of clever substitution a closed form solution of $p(m)$ can be found. Obviously, $p(\rho)$ will have fractional power terms for the odd powers, and thus directly applying the method is not possible. However, does this ring a bell for you? You seem a lot more experienced in the field

Can you post a link to the source papers from which this problem originated?

The paper containing the polynomial is "A cylindrical shell with an arbitrarily oriented crack" (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020768383900227) , while the one with the substitution for the even octic is "Transverse shear effect in a circumferentially cracked
cylindrical shell" (https://www.ams.org/journals/qam/1979-37-03/S0033-569X-1979-99633-8/S0033-569X-1979-99633-8.pdf).
I was now thinking about exploiting the fact that the seventh order coefficient is zero, and looking if something analogous to "complete the squares" could be done

To avoid misunderstanding, I am aware that "completing the squares" doesn't really have an equivalent for orders > 4. However, I am wondering if somehow by "completing" higher binomial terms something useful could be found.

@DesperateGrad See the totally revised approach in my latest posting, above.

@DesperateGrad You can contact me at rdiazmath@gmail.com if you have follow-up questions

FYI. I fixed a typo involving the identity $\cosh^2t -\sinh^2 t=1$
